# Can't fetch properties from Config service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a config service which gets data from a json file using HTTP get. I want to use these properties in other services and components.

config.json

```
{
 "prod":"false",
 "gql":{
        "uri":"abc.com"
        "cID":"123"
        }
 "token":"asdfg345"
}
```

appConfig.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ConfigService {
  configData: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  async loadConfig() {
    const data = await this.httpClient
      .get<any>("./assets/config.json")
      .toPromise();
    this.configData = data;
    console.log(this.configData);
    return data;
  }

  getconfig() {
    if (!this.configData) {
      console.error("config could not be loaded from app config service.");
    }
    return this.configData;
  }
}
```

To display all properties and prod property from the json file in app.component.ts, I tried this and it worked:

```
constructor(private config:ConfigService){}
display(){
console.log(this.config.getconfig())
console.log(this.config.getconfig().prod)
}
```

But the same does not work in another service. When I tried to console log the same things in another service, i got 2 errors'

- ***config could not be loaded from app config service***
- ***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined***

How should I read these properties in services?

Comment: check if `ConfigService` is a `singelton`. by logging something to console from it's constructor

Comment: @EliPorush what should I log?

Comment: Did the `loadConfig` function called before calling `getconfig()`?

Comment: @YongShun no i dont think so :/ where should I be calling it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need an [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) in order to make use of `ConfigService` as a singleton and share the config `data` through the entire application.

1. Register `ConfigService` in `root`.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfigService {
  ...
}
```

2. Implement a factory method. This ensures that the `loadConfig` method is being called at the start of the application.

```js
export function initializeAppFactory(configService: ConfigService) {
  return async () => {
    await configService.loadConfig();
  };
}
```

3. Register the `APP_INITIALIZER` and provide the dependencies in the root module.

```js
@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6qnpqr?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: Okay, I tried this. The problem still persists.

Comment: Can you specify what is your current problem? Or you may create a reproducible demo in StackBlitz.

Comment: The problem is that when i try to log any value from the json file in a service rather than a component then I get the two errors mentioned above
-config could not be loaded from app config service
-TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined